# How to use react router with MUI tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Can you please explain how I make my routes work with MUI tabs?
Since I don't write my code like this and do not use MUI very often, I don't understand how to make it work. any ideas please?

- I removed the imports to focus on the main problem and make the code shorter.

This is my NavBar.js Component:

```
  const NavBar = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (_e, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static" color="transparent" style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0 }}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Navigation"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
      >
        <Tab label="Home" index={0} />
        <Tab label="Favorites" index={1} />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

And my AppRouter.js Component

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? You only render one route with `Home` component on it. What are you trying to link to? You might've stripped out too much for your example.

Comment: In my Switch I added new Route like this:
 
`<Route exact path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />` 

But how I make it switch when I click on the Favorite Tab? I'm used to use Link from react-router to switch between pages.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I found the solution.
In my AppRouter.js I got this:

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home, Favorites } from "pages";
import { ThemeProvider } from "theme";
import NavBar from "components/NavBar";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

and in my NavBar.js I added this and it allows me to switch between them:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AppBar, Tabs, Tab } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Home, Favorites } from "pages";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (_e, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };


  return (
    <AppBar position="static" color="transparent" style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0 }}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Navigation"
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
      >
        <Tab label="Home" index={0} component={Link} to={"/"} />
        <Tab label="Favorites" index={1} component={Link} to={"/favorites"} />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

the problem I face now is that for some reason I lose my local storage and I change my route

Comment: When you say "lose local storage" do you mean the local component state for each routed component? If this is the case then it's common to lift state up to a common ancestor that remains mounted. React context can help here so you won't need to explicitly pass state down as props. React-redux is an app state management library (*also built on the Context API*) that allows components to subscribe to state and uses dispatched actions to effect changes to state.

Comment: Can you explain what it means: "lift the state up to a common ancestor that remains mounted"? I'm using here local storage, which is in one place regardless of which cmp I'm using.

Comment: It means moving it to a parent component or higher in the React tree that stays mounted, unlike routes/tabs and routed/tabbed components, etc.. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). I see here you mean *actual* localStorage, not local component state. Can you clarify what you mean by "lose my localStorage"?

Comment: Yes :)
I mean the actuall localStorage. I have useState for my favorites array and than I try to save it in my local storage but after I ghit the refresh button or switch to another route, my local storage becomes empty.

Comment: Since this looks to be a separate issue, it's off-topic here. Care to post a new question on SO with the component code with the state you are persisting to localStorage that is getting wiped after clicking the button or switching routes/tabs? Probably the code from your answer here plus the new relevant details. Feel free to ping (at me) me here with a link to the new question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add in `handleChange` hard coded routing, like `history.push` based on value? Not sure is it what you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).